# Counting row occurrences and printing them

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

A MySQL table named Tags contains 2 columns: tags and video_id with over 100k rows.
None of them is primary key which means that values in the tags column might occur few times with different video_id, for example:

```
column names:  |tags|video_id|
values:         tag1 video1
                tag1 video2
                tag2 video4
                tag2 video5
                tag2 video6
```

How can I count all the occurrences of each tag and print it? Something like:

> tag1 (2 Videos)
>
> tag2 (3 Videos)

My website is based on CakePHP-3, the way I get the rows from the table is like that:

```
$query = $this->Tags->find('all');
$tags = $this->paginate($query);
```

The variable tags now has the results and that's how I print them:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag):
        echo $tag->tags."<br>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: you can create an array with a tags"key"

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (x.x.x), and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584003/cakephp-3-count-group-find-result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by leveraging basic SQL logic, that is for example count `video_id` (or `*`, which might give you better performance under certain circumstances) and group by `tags`.

```
$query = $this->Tags->find();
$query = $query
    ->select([
        'tags',
        'count' => $query->func()->count('video_id')
    ])
    ->group('tags');

$tags = $this->paginate($query);
```

This will create a query similar to:

```sql
SELECT tags, COUNT(video_id) as count
FROM tags
GROUP BY tags
```

The resulting entities will hold the `count` property that you can access like any other property. Here's a small example, additionally using plural aware translation functions (surely not required, but might be useful):

```
foreach ($tags as $tag):
    echo $tag->tags . ' (' .
        __n('{0} Video', '{0} Videos', $tag->count, $tag->count) .
    ')<br>';
endforeach;
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Aggregates - Group and Having](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having)**
- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Plurals](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#plurals)**
- **[MySQL Manual > Tutorial / Creating and Using a Database / Retrieving Information from a Table / Counting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use cakephp `count()` function and `Group` options

```
$query = $this->Tags->find('all');
$tags = $query->select([ 
              'tags',
              'count' => $query->func()->count('*')
            ])
     ->group('tags');
```

you can get result by

```
foreach ($tags as $tag):
        echo $tag->tags."(".$tag->count." Videos)";
endforeach;
```

Comment: You missed $ just before tag.